# Access to the site without a port

Tags: server, nginx

My nginx listen on port 33333

```
listen 33333;
```

in /etc/nginx/sites-available/ I have:

```
server {
    listen 33333;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
```

My website work only If I run:

> www.mydomain.com:33333

How to make it work well with the:

> www.domain.com

Without giving the port.

**Note: My port 80 is used by apache. I can not change it.**

Comment: Sorry, but www.domain.com will connect you, by default, to port 80, and this is the port nginx should listen to. Either put a proxy between your machine and the rest of the world which will map 80 to 33333; or move apache to another port (e.g. 8080). You can also configure iptables to map incoming traffic from 80 to 333333. See http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/. But then you cannot access your apache server.

Comment: P.S. What do you mean by "I can not change it" -- you cannot, or you don't know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I gave you an answer to this in [your last question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315811/nginx-will-not-start). You need to tell Apache to proxy nginx so that when a request comes in for your domain, it gets routed through.

You're going to want to use the `ProxyPass`/`ProxyPassReverse` arguments in the settings for your Apache virtual host.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName "mydomain.com"
    ProxyRequests Off

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:33333/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:33333/
 </VirtualHost>
```

So now when you visit `mydomain.com`, Apache routes the request through to the secondary server.

If you need more examples, Google "apache reverse proxy".